NUMA CPU affinity issue
I have a Ubuntu server with 22.04 OS. I encountered an issue with NUMA affinity bound.
1.) Server has two NUMA nodes accordingly.
server-1:# numactl -H
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
node 0 size: 1031782 MB
node 0 free: 989481 MB
node 1 cpus: 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191
node 1 size: 1021920 MB
node 1 free: 1018313 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10

2.) When I setting CPU Affinity for a new process with cpu 0 which is part of numa node0, it spanned multiple cpu's among both numa nodes.
server-1:# taskset -c 0 cat /dev/random >& /dev/null &
[1] 2685342

server-1:# taskset -cp 2685342
pid 2685342's current affinity list: 0,1,30,48-51,96,97,144-147

I think it should stick cpu 0 rather than multi cpu. Can you please let me know how this happened.
EDIT:
server-1:# strace -e sched_setaffinity -fyy taskset -p 0 2947449
pid 2947449's current affinity mask: f00000000000300000000000f000040000003
sched_setaffinity(2947449, 24, [])      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
taskset: failed to set pid 2947449's affinity: Invalid argument
+++ exited with 1 +++


server-1:# grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/2947449/status
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-1,30,48-51,96-97,144-147

Edit-2:
-- Initiated process on cpu 1.
server-1:# taskset -c 1 cat /dev/random >& /dev/null &
[1] 691247

-- Queried taskset shows remains same. Why this values are constant. 
server-1:# taskset -cp 691247
pid 691247's current affinity list: 0,1,30,48-51,96,97,144-147

-- changed task over cpu 5 using strace and it was successful. 
server-1:# strace -e sched_setaffinity -fyy taskset -p 5 691247
pid 691247's current affinity mask: f00000000000300000000000f000040000003
sched_setaffinity(691247, 24, [0, 2])   = 0
pid 691247's new affinity mask: 5
+++ exited with 0 +++

-- Again, queried taskset shows previous which is not 5. 
server-1:# taskset -cp 691247
pid 691247's current affinity list: 0,1,30,48-51,96,97,144-147```


Could you try to set the affinity of the running cat with strace -e sched_setaffinity -fyy taskset  -p f  <cat_PID> ?  Share the output, please.

Thanks for looking into it. I reproduced another process and ran the command you provided.
server-:# taskset -c 0 cat /dev/random >& /dev/null &
[1] 2886218

server-1:# taskset -cp 2886218
pid 2886218's current affinity list: 0,1,30,48-51,96,97,144-147

server-1:# strace -e sched_setaffinity -fyy taskset  -p f 2886218
pid 2886218's current affinity mask: f00000000000300000000000f000040000003
sched_setaffinity(2886218, 24, [0, 1, 2, 3]) = 0
pid 2886218's new affinity mask: f
+++ exited with 0 +++

Play with the affinity and set it to 0, not to f. strace -e sched_setaffinity -fyy taskset  -p 0 <cat_PID>  And add the output to the question. You can verify the affinity with: grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/<PID>/status

hi @MirceaVutcovici, Added the output in questions' EDIT.

Sorry. I put the wrong mask, Try with the mask 1, which is the first CPU only. Mask 0 is invalid because represents no CPUs.

hi @MirceaVutcovici, updated output in Edit-2 in question section. Not sure why taskset always shows "current affinity list: 0,1,30,48-51,96,97,144-147" though we changed core. This value considered as default and configured some where else ?

5 is not CPU 5, but the list CPU 0, and CPU 2 as you can see in the list [0,2] from  sched_setaffinity(691247, 24, [0, 2]) syscall. But it is not setting it. Like the kernel has ignored it. Could you try with a different distribution or a different kernel?

5₁₀ = 101₂ = [0, 2]  The argument 5 is a CPU binary mask. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Are you running in a container?
CPU affinity is ignored in containers like OpenVZ, LXC or LXD, Docker, Podman...
In containers sched_setaffinity syscall is ignored.

Hi @MirceaVutcovici, No. It is physical server with Ubuntu 22.04

I tried it on Dell has Intel Xeon-Broadwell with same kernel where it is working as desired.
